# I cry for or I am crying for

Tags: continuous

Shall I  say "I am crying for you" or "I cry for you"? if my closest friend  recently died . I think "I cry for you" would  be better as emotions are often expressed by the present simple.
But I am not sure.

Comment: "I am crying for you" seems rather more colloquial than "I cry for you." But if English isn't your first language I'm sure your friend would find either sentence touching and sympathetic.

Comment: In my fact my question is can I say I am crying if I am not doing it right now  like reading , I am reading now could mean that I am not reading the book now but this is  the book I have begun to read or currently reading .

Comment: It may be worth noting that even though [***to weep*** is far less common than ***to cry*** overall](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+weep%2Cto+cry&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), the specific construction [***I weep for you*** is more common than ***I cry for you***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+weep+for+you+and%2CI+cry+for+you+and&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) But neither are particularly Anglophonic things to say, by comparison with, for example, ***I feel your pain*** (not *I am feeling your pain*).

Comment: "Crying over you" is another possible expression. But maybe not here, for the same reasons as above.

Comment: Where and when are you expressing it? Context is everything, resistance is futile. (Startrek)

Answer (score 0):

Both would be completely understandable, or you could even say 'I'm crying with you' to show you're alongside someone in their sadness. Another alternative that would sometimes be heard is 'I'm really sorry for your loss', although it is less emotive than the options you suggested.

Comment: NO this is  only a language learning question not a real situation

Comment: Oh good - I'm glad! I'll edit my answer :) Hope it was still helpful!

Comment: so what is the difference in meaning  between these two forms ?

Comment: 'I am crying for' is present continuous tense, so implies you are crying right now but have been in the past, and will continue to do so. 'I cry for' is the simple present tense, so perhaps more general., and has less indication of time.

Comment: So may be I cry for you is better because it is  not limited by the time